# data from only one table is fetched and feeded.Data is not fetched from the other

Tags: php, xampp

I am unable to find the error in the syntax.The result I get is data is only fetched from a table and fed to other table but not fetched from  another table.

```php
<?php

include "new.php";

$cgpa = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['cgpa']);
$browser = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['browser']);

$sql = "SELECT ROLLNO,NAME,DEPARTMENT,CGPA FROM l3 WHERE CGPA >= '$cgpa'";
$sql3 = "SELECT SYSTEMNUMBER FROM l2 WHERE BROWSER= '$browser'";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$result1 = mysqli_query($link, $sql3);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO l4 (ROLLNO,NAME,DEPARTMENT,CGPA)VALUES({$row['ROLLNO']},'{$row["NAME"]}','{$row["DEPARTMENT"]}',{$row["CGPA"]})";
        mysqli_query($link, $sql2);
    }
}

else
    echo "No records found.";
  //  mysqli_close($link);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
        $sql4 = "UPDATE l4 (SYSTEMNUMBER)VALUES({$row['SYSTEMNUMBER']})";
        mysqli_query($link, $sql4);
    }
}

else
    echo "No records found.";

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: are you actually sure about the syntax you used for $sql4 syntax?

Comment: no.I am really looking for the correct syntax

Comment: Have you tried to have a look on MySQL documentation or to google for something like “update query example “. Pretty much sure you can have the answer you are looking for.